# Setting screen size manually

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

What I essentially want to do is to stop a Flutter Web application from being responsive to the browser size. I want to set the "screen size" manually, thus setting a fixed canvas size. If the user wants to access anything, he should be able to zoom into the canvas, to the specific widget.

Is there a way to achieve this?
I hope it's clear what I want to do. Thank you in advance!